# Error when returning value in C# 2.0

Tags: c#

I downloaded an example application for using some web services with an online system.

I am not sure if all code below is needed but it is what I got and what I am trying to do is to use the search function.

I start by calling searchCustomer with an ID I have:

```
partnerRef.internalId = searchCustomer(customerID);
```

And the code for searchCustomer:

```
private string searchCustomer(string CustomerID)
        {

            string InternalID = "";

            CustomerSearch custSearch = new CustomerSearch();
            CustomerSearchBasic custSearchBasic = new CustomerSearchBasic();

            String nameValue = CustomerID;
            SearchStringField entityId = null;

                entityId = new SearchStringField();
                entityId.@operator = SearchStringFieldOperator.contains;
                entityId.operatorSpecified = true;
                entityId.searchValue = nameValue;
                custSearchBasic.entityId = entityId;

            String statusKeysValue = "";
            SearchMultiSelectField status = null;
            if (statusKeysValue != null && !statusKeysValue.Trim().Equals(""))
            {
                status = new SearchMultiSelectField();
                status.@operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf;
                status.operatorSpecified = true;
                string[] nskeys = statusKeysValue.Split(new Char[] { ',' });

                RecordRef[] recordRefs = new RecordRef[statusKeysValue.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < nskeys.Length; i++)
                {
                    RecordRef recordRef = new RecordRef();
                    recordRef.internalId = nskeys[i];
                    recordRefs[i] = recordRef;
                }
                status.searchValue = recordRefs;
                custSearchBasic.entityStatus = status;
            }


            custSearch.basic = custSearchBasic;

            SearchResult response = _service.search(custSearch);

            if (response.status.isSuccess)
            {

                processCustomerSearchResponse(response);




                    if (seachMoreResult.status.isSuccess)
                    {

                        processCustomerSearchResponse(seachMoreResult);

                        return InternalID;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _out.error(getStatusDetails(seachMoreResult.status));

                    }

            }
            else
            {
                _out.error(getStatusDetails(response.status));
            }

            return InternalID;
        }
```

In the code above processCustomerSearchResponse gets called

```
processCustomerSearchResponse(response);
```

The code for this function is:

```
public string processCustomerSearchResponse(SearchResult response)
{
    string InternalID = "";
    Customer customer;

        customer = (Customer)records[0];
        InternalID = customer.internalId;

        return InternalID;
}
```

What the original code did was to write some output in the console but I want to return  the InternalID instead. When I debug the application InternalID in processCustomerSearchResponse contains the ID I want but I don't know how to pass it to searchCustomer so that function also returns the ID. When I debug searchCustomer InternalID is always null. I am not sure on how to edit the code under `response.status.isSuccess`
to return the InternalID, any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `processCustomerSearchResponse(response);`, you need to store the return value in memory.

Try modifying your code like this:

```
 InternalID = processCustomerSearchResponse(response);
```